# problems expunging object from sqlalchemy in python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have the following test code that is giving me fits.  I have an open session (self.session) that may have un-committed entities in it that I don't want to perturb.
I want to delete a Propery entity that I know is not related to anything else (its safe to delete).  I create a new session and delete it.  I can confirm that it is deleted from the database.

Now, I want to make sure it is removed from the original self.session and this is where I am having problems.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, sessionmaker

from database.property import Property


def get_session() -> Session:
    engine = create_engine('a legitimate string that connects to my MySql database')
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
    return session


class TestingOnly:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = get_session()

    @staticmethod
    def in_all(session: Session,
               prop_id: int) -> bool:
        all_properties = session.query(Property).all()

        for p in all_properties:
            if p.id == prop_id:
                return True
        return False

    @staticmethod
    def delete_prop(prop):
        session = get_session()
        deleting_prop = session.get(Property, prop.id)
        session.delete(deleting_prop)
        session.commit()
        session.close()

    def start(self):
        prop = self.session.query(Property).first()
        prop_id = prop.id
        assert TestingOnly.in_all(self.session, prop_id)
        TestingOnly.delete_prop(prop)
        self.session.flush()
        self.session.expire(prop)
        self.session.expunge(prop)
        self.session.expire_all()
        #################################
        # This throws an assertion error:
        assert not TestingOnly.in_all(self.session, prop_id)


def main():
    testing_only = TestingOnly()
    testing_only.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am still having the same issue with the following code (obviously I am missing something):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, sessionmaker
from database.property import Property


class TestingOnly:
    engine = create_engine('a legitimate string that connects to my MySql database')

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = self.get_session()

    def get_session(self) -> Session:
        session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)()
        return session

    @staticmethod
    def in_all(session: Session,
               prop_id: int) -> bool:
        all_properties = session.query(Property).all()

        for p in all_properties:
            if p.id == prop_id:
                return True
        return False

    def delete_prop(self, prop):
        session = self.get_session()
        deleting_prop = session.get(Property, prop.id)
        session.delete(deleting_prop)
        session.commit()
        session.close()

    def start(self):
        prop = self.session.query(Property).first()
        prop_id = prop.id
        assert TestingOnly.in_all(self.session, prop_id)
        self.delete_prop(prop)
        # self.session.flush()
        # self.session.expire(prop)
        # self.session.expunge(prop)
        # self.session.expire_all()
        #################################
        # This throws an assertion error:
        assert not TestingOnly.in_all(self.session, prop_id)


def main():
    testing_only = TestingOnly()
    testing_only.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

More changes (still doesn't work):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, sessionmaker
from database.property import Property


class TestingOnly:
    engine = create_engine('a legitimate string that connects to my MySql database')

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = self.get_session()

    def get_session(self) -> Session:
        session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)()
        return session

    @staticmethod
    def in_all(session: Session,
               prop_id: int) -> bool:
        all_properties = session.query(Property).all()

        for p in all_properties:
            if p.id == prop_id:
                return True
        return False

    def delete_prop(self, prop):
        session = self.get_session()
        deleting_prop = session.get(Property, prop.id)
        session.delete(deleting_prop)
        session.commit()
        session.close()

    def add_property(self) -> int:
        session = self.get_session()
        prop = Property()
        session.add(prop)
        session.flush()
        prop_id = prop.id
        session.commit()
        session.close()
        return prop_id

    def verify_property_exists(self, prop_id: int) -> bool:
        session = self.get_session()
        prop = session.get(Property, prop_id)
        return prop is not None

    def start(self):
        prop_id = self.add_property()
        self.verify_property_exists(prop_id)
        prop = self.session.get(Property, prop_id)
        assert self.in_all(self.session, prop_id)
        self.delete_prop(prop)
        #self.session.flush()
        #self.session.expire(prop)
        #self.session.expunge(prop)
        #self.session.expire_all()
        #################################
        # This throws an assertion error:
        assert not TestingOnly.in_all(self.session, prop_id)


def main():
    testing_only = TestingOnly()
    testing_only.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: is there a reason you are forcing each new session to be associated with a new engine? typically one engine is recommended for an entire program. While having new engines for each test is not "wrong", having multiple engines within the same test seems off to me

Comment: Only because I didn't know any better :-/  Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: fwiw, if I modify it to use a global engine, your test passes (both asserts), you don't even have to do `flush`, `expire`, `expunge` and `expire_all` after `TestingOnly.delete_prop(prop)`, just do `assert not TestingOnly.in_all(self.session, prop_id)` after you delete using `TestingOnly.delete_prop(prop)`

Comment: I tried your changes to the code (see edits to the OP) but am getting the same issue.

Comment: one thing that I didn't mention is I manually added a row for `Property`, so my table only has one row, in your tests how and where are you getting a row to delete? (I do not see code for inserts, only a delete after a fetch)

Comment: when I say "manually" I mean I did this `self.session.add(Property())` and `self.session.commit()` as the first two lines under `start`

Comment: Probably the first session is still holding the property because it is in a separate transaction and has no way to know that property was removed.  It is unclear what this test is trying to confirm though.  Are you trying to check if deleted objects are removed from other active sessions?

Comment: Does your code work if the `delete_prop()` function uses `session = self.session` instead of `session = self.get_session()` ?

Comment: that's not really the point; I want to delete it from another session and ensure that self.session "sees" that the propery has been deleted.

Comment: I had a bunch of Property objects in the database already, but I added some code (see OP) to show where it is added.

Comment: my bad, I tried in sqlite and it was working, it does actually fail in mysql, I think its due to isolation level, setting `engine = create_engine(connection_string, isolation_level='READ COMMITTED')` seems to help with the tests

Comment: any luck here @jordanthompson

Comment: I punted for now: I am just ignoring the problem in hopes that eventually the solution will present itself. For now I've included the entity in self.session and of course it works (but it doesn't really solve the original problem)

Comment: just want to know :) why do you think the suggestion regarding isolation level is not a solution? to me that fixes the problem and it points me towards a reason. what would constitute a solution in your opinion?

Comment: IMO @python_user nailed it. The default isolation level for MySQL is REPEATABLE READ. Many other DBMSs default to READ COMMITTED. (And transaction handling in SQLite is a bit unusual because it is not primarily a multi-user database.)

Comment: @python_user I'm really sorry, I must doubled with you and I only just got back to this. Your solution seems to be working. Thank you for your help

Comment: @jordanthompson no apologies needed :) glad to know you were not being dismissive

Answer (score 1):

@python_user'solution is working for me.
engine = create_engine(connection_string, isolation_level='READ COMMITTED')